# PHP MYSQL import excel serialized data

Tags: php

I have a column with serialized data in mysql table.

How to import excell file where I have column like colors where are stored serilized data for checboxes in mysql

and need to import from excel file column

colors  colors  colors
white   yellow  blue  -> serialized into 1 column in mysql

structure of excell file can be different.

thanks

mysql table
id | name  | colors
1  | house | serialized(yelow,blue...)

excell file
name | color  | color
house| yellow | blue

I'm not sure if is the right way to handle excell file maybe something like this:

name | color
house| (yellow;blue)

Comment: Are these xls or xlsx files? Do you want to do this on Windows with Excel installed, or on linux?

Comment: there is no files yet could be any xls or csv i have php/flash upload class to server than i have to read the file and here is fun begin.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer:
[link text](http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer)

Comment: Joomla is bad. It don't aptitude OOP.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the spreadsheet to CSV. You can read the file contents with fgetcsv(), and save it to the db serialized.

Some code:

```
$dbh = new PDO($connectionstring, $username, $password);
$handle = fopen('foo.csv', 'r');
fgetcsv($handle); // omit the first line
while($row = fgetcsv($handle)) {
  $name = array_shift($row);
  $stmt = $dbh
    ->prepare('INSERT INTO table(name, data) VALUES(:name, :data);');
  $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':data', serialize($row), PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: question is how find out the column to be serialized? could you please give an example?

Comment: I need to identify somehow header with data to be serialized

Comment: mysql table 
id | name  | colors
1  | house | serialized(yelow,blue...)

excell file
name | color  | color|
house| yellow | blue

I'm not sure if is the right way to handle excell file maybe something like this:

name | color  
house| (yellow;blue)

and then find this column and implode foreach?
placed in forst post for better reading